# Install python3-pip

Tags: python3

I am running Ubuntu 22.04

Can someone please explain to me what is happening here:

```
root@mail:~# pip3 install --user pyznap
Command 'pip3' not found, but can be installed with:
apt install python3-pip
root@mail:~# apt install python3-pip
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
python3-pip is already the newest version (22.0.2+dfsg-1ubuntu0.4).
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove, and 0 not upgraded.
```

**EDIT**:

I do not know if the answer given by GAD3R is correct or not, I haven't tried it.

The issue is why is Ubuntu on the one hand telling me pip3 is not installed and then when I try to install it Ubuntu claims it is already installed.

This is not right.

**EDIT**:

The below command solved the problem.

```
/usr/bin/pip3.10 install --user pyznap
```

It seems `python3-pip` is not installed correctly on my system. What is the best way to rectify this? Is `sudo apt install --reinstall python3-pip` a good option?

EDIT:

```
root@mail:~# python3
Python 3.10.12 (main, Nov 20 2023, 15:14:05) [GCC 11.4.0] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
```

Comment: The [`python3-pip` package in 22.04](https://packages.ubuntu.com/jammy-updates/all/python3-pip/filelist) provides  `/usr/bin/pip`, `/usr/bin/pip3`, and `/usr/bin/pip3.10`. So I'd suggest checking if those files are present in those locations, try running them directly if they are, or inspecting your command history to see what might have caused them to not be there.

Comment: Which Python version is shown when you act as root and open the Python REPL calling `python3` from the terminal?

Comment: Information added.

Answer (score 1):

You need to exit the root shell (to use the `--user` option), then run:

```
$ python3 -m pip install --user pyznap
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems `python3-pip` is not installed correctly on my system so I did

```
sudo apt install --reinstall python3-pip
```

Now I can install programs with pip3.